# EntityProxies with immutable ValueProxy properties -> "could not locate setter"

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I'm trying to wrap my mind around RequestFactory, but I'm having some problems. I have an entityproxy that has a property which is a valueproxy of an immutable type (joda-time LocalDate), and I'm having problems using this entityproxy in any calls to the server.

I've made the property read-only by only including a getter for the property in the entityproxy, and only including getters for the primitive properties in the valueproxy.

However, as far as I can tell, If I use an entityproxy as an argument in a call to a service method, any referenced valueproxy is automatically marked as edited and all its properties are included in the delta?

This in turn causes ReflectiveServiceLayer to throw an exception about a missing setter on LocalDate.

I've been toying with the idea of implementing a ServiceLayerDecorator which overrides "setProperty" to get around this, but I'm not sure if that's a good solution. Is there any "proper" way to fix this? Ideally, I'd like AbstractRequestContext not to include immutable properties in calls to the server.

I'm using GWT 2.3

edit:  I created a workaround like this, but I'm still unsure of whether this is the correct approach:

```
public class ImmutablePropertyFixServiceLayer extends ServiceLayerDecorator {
    @Override
    public void setProperty(Object domainObject, String property, Class<?> expectedType, Object value) {
        Method setter = getTop().getSetter(domainObject.getClass(), property);
        if (setter != null) {
            super.setProperty(domainObject, property, expectedType, value);
        } else {
            //System.out.println(domainObject.getClass().getName() + "." + property + " doesn't have a setter");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EntityProxy objects have some way they can be easily retreived on the server, so when sending an object back to the server, just the ID is required. ValueProxy objects on the other hand can only be sent as the combination of all of their sub-values. When sending an immutable value back to the server, the server code doesn't know how to turn a proxy back into a server-side value.

I'd be concerned with your solution that you might not be correctly getting the same date on the server as was sent from the client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've since skipped using RequestFactory, as I found that limitations I kept running into imposed constraints on how I could implement my domain objects that killed the point of using RequestFactory over some DTO solution in the first place (did that make any sense? :)

Anyway, the problem I had

Comment: ... in this case was that value proxy objects were getting marked as edited when they shouldn't have. RF has some mechanism to only send differential changes back to the server, but this only seemed to apply to primitive properties and didn't extend to primitives inside value proxies? In this case it was a problem, since RF on the server side kept trying to change properties on the immutable object that the value proxy represented..

Comment: One more comment to clarify: none of these objects were actually getting created on the client, so there was no case where ignoring the property supplied by the client might have led to an inconsistent state (as the property that the client was trying to supply was immutable, i.e. not modifiable).

Comment: Full ValueProxy instances must be sent to the server, since there is nothing to diff them against, but it stores the full set of properties as a list of setters to call. RequestFactory can't solve every problem, it isn't intended to be a general replacement for RPC. It tends to be a very good fit for some problems, and nearly useless for others, whereas RPC almost always requires some accommodation to make it work.

Comment: Note that I'm talking about the valueproxy as a *property* of an entityproxy.

As far as I remember making an entityproxy editable clones it and all its properties, so the original unmodified version of the valueproxy remains and could be diffed against. AbstractRequestContext (or the diff function from autobeans that it uses, I don't remember precisely) had some logic that simply always marked a property as 'edited' if it happened to be a valueproxy..

Of course, it's been a while since I dug around in the code, so I might be wrong..

Comment: No, unless I am misunderstanding you, that is not correct - the server RF wiring doesn't keep a copy of either ValueProxies or EntityProxies while the client is editing, since the server can't tell what objects the client will edit, and which ones it is just displaying.

Comment: I'm not talking about the server at all :) My point was simply that http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html -> 'the EntityProxy interface enables RequestFactory to compute and send only changes ("deltas") to the server' doesn't, for some reason, work with ValueProxy properties of EntityProxies.

Comment: 'the EntityProxy interface enables RequestFactory to compute and send only changes ("deltas") to the server' - the important part of that sentance as it relates to your comment is 'EntityProxy', which is to say not a ValueProxy. ValueProxy properties (or other values like strings) are sent as a whole - strings are not sent as new chars added, nor are numbers sent as the difference between the old an new values.

Comment: I get that, but seeing as there's loads of bean traversal logic built into all of this it shouldn't be that difficult to check if the ValueProxy property has been modified or not. It's not like I don't understand why I ran into the problem I did, I was just asking if anyone had come up with a reasonable way around it.

Comment: Yep, probably true - this may not work well in general, given the fact that a well connected object graph getting reconnected in some other way, and as it is a value there is no way to reconstitute it - at least not in a general sense. One option might be to define your value as a EntityProxy, and build a Locator that reads it from the parent object it came from - give it an id based on its parent and the property name. RF is built on AutoBeans which provide lots of useful bean-traversal stuff if you should decide to try building your own based on ValueProxy.